# Aweber authorization code not working

Tags: php, api, aweber

Here is weird problem: when I authorize my Aweber app, the authorization code works the first time.

However when I refresh the page I get an error:
    AWeberAPIException:

```
Type: UnauthorizedError 
Msg : RequestToken key is invalid.     https://labs.aweber.com/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized
```

Docs: https://labs.aweber.com/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized

Please help this is really frustrating. Here is the code I'm using:

```
require_once('aweber_api/aweber_api.php');

try {
# set $authorization_code to the code that is given to you from
# https://auth.aweber.com/1.0/oauth/authorize_app/YOUR_APP_ID
    $authorization_code="Azh...";

$auth = AWeberAPI::getDataFromAweberID($authorization_code);
list($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessKey, $accessSecret) = $auth;

# Store the Consumer key/secret, as well as the AccessToken key/secret
# in your app, these are the credentials you need to access the API.
//$account = $aweber->getAccount($accessKey, $accessSecret);

}
catch(AWeberAPIException $exc) {
print "<h3>AWeberAPIException:</h3>";
print " <li> Type: $exc->type              <br>";
print " <li> Msg : $exc->message           <br>";
print " <li> Docs: $exc->documentation_url <br>";
print "<hr>";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

OK, I solved it!

The authorization token contains `$consumerKey`, `$consumetSecret`, `$accessKey`, and `$accessSecret`

The following line returns an `Array`

```
$auth = AWeberAPI::getDataFromAweberID($authorization_code);
```

So,

```
$consumerKey = $auth[0];
$consumerSecret = $auth[1];
$accessKey = $auth[2];
$accessSecret = $auth[3];
```

And then you simply use those values to authorize the application! Of course, if it's used by multiple users you need to store these values for each of them.

Comment: Missing in this answer: make sure you call `AWeberAPI::getDataFromAweberID()` once in a lifetime, in other words, you need to store the other credentials in a database...Yes, you don't have another choice.